# ShowMessageDialog - Components

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

I think my question is very simple for you.
I am recently starting with programming.
I would like to know exactly what it's doing the null of the showMesageDialog(null,"string").

I always see that people set null, but I don't know exactly why is the reason to put null.

I put an example.

Hope you can help me.

```
"JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR DE PENSION");"

//1. Definicion de variables


        int pension;
        String categoria;
        Double Promedio;
        Double Descuento;

        categoria = txtTP.getText().toString();
        System.out.println("hola" +categoria);
        if (categoria.equalsIgnoreCase("A"))
            pension = 550;

        else
            if(categoria.equalsIgnoreCase("B"))
                pension = 500;

            else
                if(categoria.equalsIgnoreCase("C"))
                    pension = 460;
                else
                    if (categoria.equalsIgnoreCase("D"))
                    pension = 400;
                    else
                    pension = 0;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR DE PENSION");
```

Comment: Consider using Stack Overflow Spanish: https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I wrote too fast. Sorry for the wrong words.

Comment: @Fernando.F Upvote or accept the answer if this/any answer is/was helpful to you for the benefit of future readers. see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Answer (score 2):

According to the Javadocs for JOptionPane:

```
public static void showMessageDialog(Component parentComponent, Object message)
```

The first parameter is the parent component. According to the documentation:

> (Parent Component) determines the Frame in which the dialog is displayed; if null, or if the parentComponent has no Frame, a default Frame is used

So by putting null you're telling it to just use the default frame.

Comment: @Fernando.F You're welcome. Also here's the Javadocs for JOptionPane, in case you wanted to read it: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of the showMessageDialog point to the parent component.
If you set null, your parent component use from the default frame.
usually central to desktop